# Android, XML parsing similar to E4X?

Tags: android, xml, e4x

I am working on a project in Android now that involves parsing XML from a local file.

I have done XML work extensiely in flex and have become used to the power and flexibility of E4X and it's capabilities. I wonder now if I can do something similar in android or will I be forced to parse the XML manually?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to parse the xml file in assets folder in your project, am i right, mate???

Comment: Yes, either in assets or in the data directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [@Andreas_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011919/java-ways-to-parse-xml-in-e4x/2011971#2011971):

> E4X is a language extension, XML is treated like a primitive. E4X is not just for parsing XML, it's using XML as real types.
>
> This can't be simulated or done with a Java 'framework', it would require a language extension for Java.

And, since Android does not have JAXB, you don't have that, either.

You have your choice of DOM, SAX, and the `XmlPullParser`, plus any third-party Java libraries you can find that have been ported to Android and fit whatever size constraints you may have.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to write my own then afterall. :(

Answer (score 2):

check this out-

[Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw82Android-XML&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grlnxw82)

Comment: Thanks. I'v seen this page before and been through it a couple of times. I decided to go for SAX in the end.